# When the left-right parenthesis is too big, how to make it smaller?

Tags: fontsize, bordermatrix

When the left-right parenthesis is too big as in the example below, how do you make the parenthesis smaller?

```
         \documentclass[reqno]{amsart} 
         \usepackage{amssymb}
         \usepackage{mathrsfs}
         \usepackage{amsmath}
         \usepackage{amsthm}
         \usepackage{stackrel} 
        \usepackage{courier}
        \usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy} 
        \usepackage{mathtools} 
        \usepackage{hyperref}
        \usepackage{multicol}
        \usepackage{enumerate}
        \usepackage{bookmark}

        \begin{document}


            $ \left(
      \bordermatrix{
        &   &        \cr 
        &a_{11} & a_{12} \cr 
        &a_{21} & a_{22} \cr 
        },
      \bordermatrix{
        &   &        \cr 
        &b_{11} & b_{12} \cr 
        &b_{21} & b_{22} \cr 
        } 
             \right) $



              \end{document}
```

The command \small doesn't seem to work; I am getting errors. I would like the outer parenthesis to be the same size as the parenthesis around the matrices.

Comment: Instead of `\left` and `\right`, you can use manual sizing commands. See here https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Manual_sizing BTW, welcome to tex.SX; it is customary here to post so called minimal working examples (MWEs) which are complete, compilable documents demonstrating your issue.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please edit your posting to create a compilable MWE (minimum working example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`) that generates the problem behavior you're looking to address. In particular, please be sure to indicate which package(s) you load that provide the `\bordermatrix` macro; there are several packages that provide just such a macro, and it's important to know which one you're using.

Comment: @Christian Thank you. I have provided minimum working example.

Comment: @Mico I have provided minimum working example. I probably added far more packages than you really need, but here it is. I hope this is helpful.

Comment: @user46728 Yep, so it's not a *minimum* working example, technically. But this is definitely more helpful than the fragment you originally posted and the great number of useful answers you got probably speak to this :)

Comment: @Christian I think all the answers have been very useful. Thank you all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the tabular or the matrix environment for your matrices, the \left and \right should always have the correct size.

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}

\begin{document}

$\left(
  \left(
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
      $a_{11}$ & $a_{12}$ \\
      $a_{21}$ & $a_{22}$ \\
    \end{tabular}
  \right)
   ,
  \left(
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
      $b_{11}$ & $b_{12}$ \\
      $b_{21}$ & $b_{22}$ \\
    \end{tabular}
  \right)
\right)$

$\left(
  \left(
    \begin{matrix}
      a_{11} & a_{12} \\
      a_{21} & a_{22} \\
    \end{matrix}
  \right)
   ,
  \left(
    \begin{matrix}
      b_{11} & b_{12} \\
      b_{21} & b_{22} \\
    \end{matrix}
  \right)
\right)$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Maarten! This worked perfectly! I will choose this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

`\bordermatrix` is a plain tex structure, and the fact that it is intended to
incorporate an extra row at the top is what is forcing the outer parentheses to be
much too large.

instead, you can use one of the `amsmath` "fenced" matrices.  `\pmatrix` is
what is recommended here:

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart} 

\begin{document}
\[
 \Biggl(
  \begin{pmatrix}
        a_{11} & a_{12} \\
        a_{21} & a_{22}
  \end{pmatrix} .
  \begin{pmatrix}
        b_{11} & b_{12} \\
        b_{21} & b_{22}
  \end{pmatrix}
 \Biggr)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

instead of `\left` and `\right` -- which in this case give outer parentheses the
same size as the inner ones, i've used `\Bigg` ones, which are just slightly
larger.

you're already using `amsart`, so you don't need to load `amsmath`.  (`amsart` also incorporates `amsthm`, so you don't need that either, although it isn't relevant
for this examples.)

Answer (score 4):

`\bordermatrix` is intended to place additional annotations in the "border" of a matrix. The empty line is seen by `\left` and `\right` and the size of the delimiters is increases. Package `amsmath` (loaded in your preamble) provides several `matrix` environments, `pmatrix` which can be used here to set a simple matrix with parentheses:

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  \left(
    \begin{pmatrix}
      a_{11} & a_{12} \\
      a_{21} & a_{22}
    \end{pmatrix},
    \begin{pmatrix}
      b_{11} & b_{12} \\
      b_{21} & b_{22}
    \end{pmatrix}
  \right)
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

Here's one of many ways:

```
  \documentclass[reqno]{amsart} 
  \usepackage{tabstackengine}
  \begin{document}
  \setstacktabbedgap{2ex}
  $\left(
  \parenMatrixstack{
    a_{11} & a_{12} \\ 
    a_{21} & a_{22}
    },
  \parenMatrixstack{
    b_{11} & b_{12} \\
    b_{21} & b_{22}
    } 
  \right) $
  \end{document}
```

[image]